# How to check if an iPhone is moved from sleep to active state programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

I have tried checking different threads with no luck.

I'm creating an application in which I wanted to get notified whenever my iDevice(iPhone/iPod/iPad) changes its state from Active to Sleep and vice versa.

I am aware about the approach when we need to achieve same at the application level,

```
- applicationWillResignActive
- applicationDidBecomeActive
```

The scenario is like, even if my application is not running in the background there should be some code which will be notifying me for the device state (Active to Sleep & Sleep to Active)

P.S: I need to Locally notify user

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So why won't `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillResignActive` work for you?

Comment: @freshking: It would not work. Because my applications might not be in background. I need something like, user unlocks the iPhone and my application will get notified about the change. Let me know if you want me share more details. thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember you can try out this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(__unused NSNotification *note) {

            // do whatever
}];
```

using names:

```
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
```

and

```
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
```